# Find matching phrases and words in a string python

Tags: python, string, nlp

Using python, what would be the most efficient way for one to extract common phrases or words from to given string?

For example,

```
string1="once upon a time there was a very large giant called Jack"
string2="a very long time ago was a very brave young man called Jack"
```

Would return:

```
["a","time","there","was a very","called Jack"]
```

How would one go about in doing this efficiently (in my case I would need to do this over thousands of 1000 word documents)?

Comment: i think regex is not needed here.

Comment: Efficiency, depending on who you ask, will vary from dev to dev. But in your case, I would say having a mix of single words and phrases in a list will not be very efficient. Maybe store each word into a database (or make your own data type) and keep track of each word that comes before and after...Which may or may not be very efficient for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can `split` each string, then `intersect` the `set`s.

```
string1="once upon a time there was a very large giant called Jack"
string2="a very long time ago was a very brave young man called Jack"
set(string1.split()).intersection(set(string2.split()))
```

Result

```
set(['a', 'very', 'Jack', 'time', 'was', 'called'])
```

Note this only matches individual words. You have to be more specific on what you would consider a "phrase". Longest consecutive matching substring? That could get more complicated.

Comment: I think the "longest consecutive matching substring" qualifies to what I meant.

Comment: Just to note that `set.intersection` takes an arbitrary iterable so just using `string2.split()` won't need the explicit `set` call

Answer (score 2):

In natural language processing, you usually extract common patterns and sequences from sentences using `n-grams`.
In python, you can use the excellent `NLTK` module for that.

For counting and finding the most common, you can use `collections.Counter`.

Here's a example for 2-grams:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

string1="once upon a time there was a very large giant called Jack"
string2="a very long time ago was a very brave young man called Jack"

n = 2
ngrams1= ngrams(string1.split(" "), n)
ngrams2= ngrams(string2.split(" "), n)

counter= Counter(chain(ngrams1,ngrams2))       #count occurrences of each n-gram
print [k[0] for k,v in counter.items() if v>1] #print all ngrams that come up more than once
```

output:

```
[('called', 'Jack'), ('was', 'a'), ('a', 'very')]
```

output with `n=3`:

```
[('was', 'a', 'very')]
```

output with `n=1` (without tuples):

```
['Jack', 'a', 'was', 'time', 'called', 'very']
```

Comment: Instead of doing `str.split()` you could use `nltk.word_tokenize()` which would account for punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic dynamic programming problem. All you need to do is build a suffix tree for `string1`, with words instead of letters (which is the usual formulation). Here is an [illustrative example of a suffix tree](http://www.primarydigit.com/uploads/2/0/1/6/20168087/3716619.png?517).

1. Label all nodes in your tree as `s1`.
2. Insert all suffixes of `string2` one by one.
3. All nodes that the suffixes in step 2 pass through are labeled `s2`.
4. Any new nodes created in step 2 are also labeled `s2`.
5. In the final tree, path labels of every node labeled both `s1` and `s2` is a common substring.

This algorithm is succinctly explained in [this lecture note](http://ai.stanford.edu/~serafim/cs262/Spring2003/Notes/11.pdf).

For two strings of lengths `n` and `m`, the suffix tree construction takes `O(max(n,m))`, and all the matching substrings (in your case, words or phrases) can be searched in `O(#matches)`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years later, but I tried this way using 'Counter' below:

Input[ ]:

```
from collections import Counter

string1="once upon a time there was a very large giant called Jack"
string2="a very long time ago was a very brave young man called Jack"
string1 += ' ' + string2
string1 = string1.split()

count = Counter(string1)
tag_count = []
for n, c in count.most_common(10):
    dics = {'tag': n, 'count': c}
    tag_count.append(dics)
```

Output[ ]:

```
[{'tag': 'a', 'count': 4},
 {'tag': 'very', 'count': 3},
 {'tag': 'time', 'count': 2},
 {'tag': 'was', 'count': 2},
 {'tag': 'called', 'count': 2},
 {'tag': 'Jack', 'count': 2},
 {'tag': 'once', 'count': 1},
 {'tag': 'upon', 'count': 1},
 {'tag': 'there', 'count': 1},
 {'tag': 'large', 'count': 1}]
```

Hopefully, it would be useful for someone :)